# ESP8266 AT firmware doesn't say it's ready

Tags: at-command, esp8266

I'm using ESP12E module. I uploaded v1.1.1.1 AT Firmware.bin, connected pin 0 from ground to 3.3 V, restarted the module.

When monitoring the COM port I see :

[image]

In the end id doesn't say that it's ready and therefore none of the AT commands work.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the image in your question, we see some garbage. On top it says

> ,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

This tells us the device had an external reset and configured to boot from flash. Thus your pin connections are correct. If we get back to garbage this tells us the loaded FW works with a different baud rate then the 74880 baud. Possibly the garbage is the "ready" message. Try to change baud rate from the terminal (arduino IDE) and reboot the module till you see the "ready" message.